# Eclipse installation error

Tags: eclipse

When i install eclipse helios in ubuntu

1. Extract the eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz using

   ```
   tar -zxvf eclipse.XX.YY.tar.gz
   ```
2. Become root.

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. Copy the extracted folder to /opt

   ```
   cp -r eclipse.XX.YY /opt
   ```
4. Create a desktop file and place it into /usr/share/applications

   ```
   gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and copy the following to the eclipse.desktop file.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Eclipse 
   Type=Application
   Exec=eclipse
   Terminal=false
   Icon=eclipse
   Comment=Integrated Development Environment
   NoDisplay=false
   Categories=Development;IDE
   Name[en]=Eclipse
   ```
5. Create a symlink in /usr/local/bin using

   ```
   cd /usr/local/bin
   ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse
   ```
6. For eclipse icon to be displayed in dash, eclipse icon can be added as

   ```
   cp /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
   ```

it give below error: **bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse: No such file or directory**

Comment: First do `ls -ltr /opt/eclipse*/eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

I decompressed the whole eclipse package in my home folder and (Apart from skipping step 2) I added in Step 5 the `sudo` part:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

in my case it looked like this

```
sudo ln -s /home/cyrex/eclipse/eclipse
```

that's the only change I did and it worked. Note that my eclipse executable was in my home eclipse folder. eg: `/home/cyrex/eclipse`.

Also make sure you have the appropriate 32 or 64 bit version.

Comment: Strange, but I thought he did a 'sudo su' to become root before everything?

Comment: @owl I may have jumped over that step lol. Maybe because I just decompressed the whole thing on my home folder. Thanks for pointing it out.